# Are there some tools to get human brain Brodmann areas from X,Y,Z coordinates?

Tags: software, neuroanatomy

Is there some program that given the x,y,z coordinates of a area in a given brain template, gives the histological Brodmann area relative to that template?

I'm interested in associating x,y,z coordinates in the ICBM152 atlas to Brodmann areas.

Something like this for example:

```
-6.2731  34.705  -5.0925  -->  Broadmann Area 23
-4.5387  46.539   3.0627  -->  Broadmann Area 24
```

Comment: I found a similar question [here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Im_looking_for_an_online_atlas_ofthe_human_brain_that_allows_input_of_xyz_coordinates_in_MNI_space_to_determine_and_label_corresponding_brain_areas).

Comment: Talairach client does the job nicely:

http://www.talairach.org/

Comment: @linello if you think that's the answer, perhaps post as an answer